# Impediments in Azure DevOps against user stories

Tags: azure-devops

I have a User Story against which there is an impediment faced in current sprint. Due to this impediment, we are not able to complete the US in this sprint. However we cannot also close it or mark it resolved. Since its open without any action, its also interfering with the burndown charts.

Can I get an advice on how we can handle impediments in Azure DevOps and thereby set that work has been halted/suspended on a particular user story? I was reading the related article here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/manage-issues-impediments?view=azure-devops.

Thanks and Regards,

Satheesh Vijayan

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation:

> You use issues or impediments to track items that may block work from
>   getting done. In general, you link these items to user stories or
>   other work items using a Related link type.

So as a workaround ,you can try customizing impediments tracking ,through this you can customize the item state,add a special state to impediment item . For details, see [Customize an inheritance process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/inheritance-process-model).

Organization Settings -> Process -> Inheritance process -> Impediment ->State -> New state

**Note**: only inheritance process can be customized.

[image]